# Printing UITableView filled with core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is this even possible?  From what I am reading, the only way to accomplish this is by creating a pdf draw of the screen to print...

I currently have a UITableView that lists items from core data.  I'd like to be able to print the tableview records.  If I have to create a PDF I guess I can.

Can I take the array that is filling the tableview to do this?

Any suggestions would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to retrieve one by one each cell of your UITableView (with uitableview delegate's cellForRowAtIndexPath) converting one by one those cell to a image (look at [how to convert UIView to UIImage without background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895090/how-to-convert-uiview-to-uiimage-without-background)) for reference, and "appending" those images to a pdf you would be creating (you would have to manage the position where to print those images and new page creation)