# Create image with outlines using core graphics

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, core-graphics

I need help to create an image similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you create a subclass of `UIView`, e.g. `CustomView`, the only thing you need to do is implement the `drawRect:` method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    // set fill & stroke color
    [[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor purpleColor] setFill];

    // create blocks
    CGFloat blockWidth = self.bounds.size.width / 3;
    CGFloat blockHeight = self.bounds.size.height;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:
            CGRectMake(blockWidth * i, 0, blockWidth, blockHeight);
        path.lineWidth = 2;
        [path fill];
        [path stroke];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I need to covert that view to image. It works for me for now.

Comment: That's rather easy: I found some code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895090/how-to-convert-uiview-to-uiimage-without-background). But in that case, you're better off using a drawing program like GIMP.